# How to do spatial search using mongodb queries?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use spatial search in my android app. I am new to mongodb and spatial search.
I am trying to implement this query in command prompt but it displays nothing

```
db.places.find( { loc: { $geoWithin : { $center : [ [x, y], 10 ] } } } )
```

Inplace of x and y i wrote longitude and latitude.
I want to do spatial search around a particular longitude and latitude. What should i write in loc, x, y?

Please help!!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you must read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/ and http://www.10gen.com/presentations/building-spatial-mongodb-apps-cloud

without any details, your question was not understandable

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/center/

Check the http://docs.mongodb.org/manual manual, it helps a lot.

Comment: Could you put the answer in your answer in addition to linking to the documentation?